# Appbundler and pkgbuild not working under Catalina: trying to install to system volume

Tags: java, macos-catalina

I have an app written in Java.  I create a .jar using Eclipse on a Windows machine, and transfer it to my Mac.  I use appbundler to create a .app directory, and pkgbuild to create a .pkg installer.  This has worked fine until upgrading to Catalina.

I'm using the latest version of appbundler that I downloaded from https://github.com/ome/appbundler.  Here's my build.xml:

```
<project name="Stopwatch" default="bundle-Stopwatch" basedir=".">
    <!-- Import environment variables -->
    <property environment="env"/>

    <taskdef name="bundleapp"
    classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"
    classpath="lib/appbundler-1.0ea.jar" />

    <target name="bundle-Stopwatch">
        <delete dir="appBundle" failonerror="false"/>
        <mkdir dir="appBundle"/>
        <bundleapp outputdirectory="appBundle"
            name="Stopwatch"
            displayname="Stopwatch"
            identifier="com.intonia.stopwatch.Stopwatch"
            icon="Stopwatch.icns"
            mainclassname="com.intonia.stopwatch.Stopwatch">
           <classpath file="Stopwatch.jar"/>
           <option value="-Xdock:icon=Stopwatch.icns"/>
       </bundleapp>
   </target>
</project>
```

I run

```
$ ant
```

to create `appBundle/Stoppwatch.app`.  Then

```
$ pkgbuild -- root appBundle Stopwatch.pkg
```

The first time I double-click `Stopwatch.pkg` in the finder, it runs to completion, and the app works, but it replaces the copy in my development directory.  To get Stopwatch installed in the Applications directory, it is necessary to run

```
$ sudo pkgutil --forget com.intonia.stopwatch.Stopwatch
```

Then when I run `Stopwatch.pkg` again, after the installer requests my password, it reports, "This package is incompatible with this version of macOS.  The package is trying to install content to the system volume."

Note that the example I've shown above is reduced to its basic elements.  I've tried it with a large, complex .jar and a small simple one.  I've tried it with and without bundling a JVM, with and without code signing.  I've been able to successfully notarize the app, but I get exactly the same results with and without notarizing.

I previously posted about this thinking it was a notarization issue, but clearly it's not.

Has anyone else been able to use appbundler and pkgbuild with a .jar file under Catalina?